# compress website content on opening keyboard on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css

On visual viewport change (i.e: keyboard open) we want to resize our page vertically. Our current approach is to capture a resizing event and change html tag’s height to match visual viewports height as follow.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleVerticalResize() {
      const clientWidth = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].clientWidth
      if (window.visualViewport.width === clientWidth) {
        // indicates that width is unchanged (e.g. keyboard opens on phone)
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.height =
          window.visualViewport.height.toString() + "px"
      }
    }
    if (window.visualViewport) {
      window.visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", handleVerticalResize)
      return () =>
        window.visualViewport.removeEventListener(
          "resize",
          handleVerticalResize
        )
    }
  }, [])
```

The visual viewport height is correctly calculated, but for some reason there’s an offsetTop which blows up the whole (i.e: picture with highlighted blue area, that’s the html tag seen from inspector)

[image]

Our solution works perfectly on Android, only gives us problems on iOS, no matter if it’s Chrome or Safari, what could it be?

how it is expected to look on IOS and how it looks on android is below:

[image]